# Building a Cocoapod with dependency on GoogleAnalytics-iOS-SDK fails validation

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

Thanks for you help in advance,

I am see linker errors when creating a private cocoapod with a dependancy on GoogleAnalytics-iOS-SDK.

The relevant section of the podspec is:

```
s.dependency 'GoogleAnalytics-iOS-SDK', '3.10'
```

Projects which include my pod build and run, just the linter fails. Meaning I can't push the pod to my repo.

```
pod lib lint --verbose
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GAI", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Test.o
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GAI", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Test.o
```

What is causing this linker error?  How do I work around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've successfully added this dependency by adding the platform limit with this instruction in the podspec of your private library to limit to iOS devices only :

```
Pod::Spec.new do |m|
    ...
    m.platform = :ios, "7.0"
```

Comment: I already have this, still fails to lint.  Does yours lint?  pod spec lint  --verbose

Comment: You're right, that doesn't "linted"... I needed to add the following flag with cocoa pods 0.36 "--use-libraries", and then it linted !

Comment: i don't understand this syntax. what is "m" and ...?